# How to derive a generic formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^p$ for any $p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm able to derive the formula where $p=1$ and $p=2$, but I don't see how the formula generalizes to higher powers without having to derive each one individually.

Is there an inductive approach? What is the name of this series?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: You can have a look at [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: By 'any $p$', do you mean any $p\in\mathbb{R}$ or $p$ can only be a positive integer? In the former case, I don't anything like Faulhaber's formula exists.

Comment: Another useful resource by Mathologer: [Power sum MASTER CLASS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw1kRz83Fj0).

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Positive integer, I mean.

Comment: @David, then the Faulhaber formula is the one you are looking for.